# Clone or Add more fields using jquery including the functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a select group of reason and other select-group for subreason. I want to add more reason but as soon as I click on the button the same field appear but it changes the value of above fields too. I need them to be independent but also perform the (reason -subreason).
**Code**

```
   <div class="tab" id="add_reason">
    
      <h4 class="card-title">Reason</h4><Br>

      <label for="roads">Select Branch</label>
      <select name="reason[]" id="reason"  class="form-control required">
              <option value="">Reasons</option>
              <option class="road"  value="Road">Road</option>
              <option class="driver" value="Driver">Driver's Fault</option>
      </select><br>
      
      <select id="subreason" name="subreason[]" class="form-control">
            <optgroup label="Road" required>
              <option>Pot Holes</option>
              <option>No boards at starting and ending point of Bridge</option>
              <option>No Painting to Divider</option>
              <option>Speed Breaker without Zebra Crossing</option>         
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Driver" required>
              <option>Lane Cutting</option>
              <option>Overtaking from Wrong side</option>
              <option>Corner Overtaking</option>
            </optgroup>
            
            </select>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-reason">Add Reasons</button>        
    
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $optgroups = $('#subreason > optgroup');
    $("#reason").on("change",function(){
    var selectedVal = this.value;
    $('#subreason').html($optgroups.filter('[label="'+selectedVal+'"]'));
    }); 
    });
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn-reason").click(function(){
      
        $('#add_reason').clone(true).appendTo('#add_reason');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to know about jQuery `.clone()` is that it creates new DOM elements from some existing ones.

That implies the same rules as any other *dynamically created* elements:

- Do not use `id`s
- Delegate event handlers

Additionnally, the cloned set of elements cannot be appended multiple places... So, to use it as a templating trick, you have to clone twice. Once on page load (to save them before any change occurs) and once again when appending somewhere.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Cloned "templates"
  let reason_wrapper = $(".reason-wrapper").clone()
  var $optgroups = $(".subreason > optgroup").clone()

  // "delegated" event handler for any existing or future .reason element
  $(document).on("change", ".reason", function() {
    var selectedVal = this.value;
    $(this)
      .closest(".reason-wrapper")
      .find(".subreason")
      .html($optgroups.clone().filter('[label="' + selectedVal + '"]'));
  });

  // "delegated" event handler for any existing or future .btn-reason element
  $(document).on("click", ".btn-reason", function() {
    reason_wrapper.clone().appendTo("#add_reason");
  });
});
```

```css
.reason-wrapper {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="tab" id="add_reason">
  <h4 class="card-title">Reason</h4>

  <div class="reason-wrapper">
    <label for="roads">Select Branch</label>
    <select name="reason[]" class="reason form-control required">
      <option value="">Reasons</option>
      <option class="road" value="Road">Road</option>
      <option class="driver" value="Driver">Driver's Fault</option>
    </select>

    <br>

    <select name="subreason[]" class="subreason form-control">
      <optgroup label="Road" required>
        <option>Pot Holes</option>
        <option>No boards at starting and ending point of Bridge</option>
        <option>No Painting to Divider</option>
        <option>Speed Breaker without Zebra Crossing</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Driver" required>
        <option>Lane Cutting</option>
        <option>Overtaking from Wrong side</option>
        <option>Corner Overtaking</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-reason">Add Reasons</button>
  </div>
</div>
```